# Why my windows will always resize to normal after calling win.ClickInput() in pywinauto

Tags: pywinauto

all,

I found a strange problem in pywinauto, when I send any key or mouse event to the application window I want, the target window will always resize, my code is as following:

```
app = pywinauto.application.Application()
comapp = app.connect(path = "myApp.exe")
win=comapp.top_window()
win.ClickInput(coords=(myX, myY),absolute=True)
```

I'm sure the last statement:

```
win.ClickInput(coords=(myX, myY),absolute=True),
```

causes the window resizing, the target window is in maximum size status.
Who could help me fix this issue? and work around it is also OK.

I like to use maximum size window, because the mouse's coordinates could be fixed when the window is in maximum size.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this! I've reproduced it for `notepad.exe`. Filed [issue #318](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/318). Will fix soon.

Comment: Is my answer resolved the problem?

Comment: Yes, Vasilly, thanks for your excellent work! I've tested your new release, this bug fix is confirmed.

Comment: Cool! 0.6.3 is also just out with a bunch of improvements (130+ commits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fixed in pywinauto 0.6.2. Just upgrade it by `pip install -U pywinauto`.